# How to register multiple key presses at the same time in python with library keyboard

Tags: python, keyboard, key, pyautogui

I want to create a program when I press ctrl and alt at the same time that refreshes the page 100 times. The only thing that doesn't work is when you press ctrl and alt at the same time. Does anyone know how to fix this. Here is my code

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard

while True:  
    try:  e
        if keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl,alt'):  
            print('You Pressed h Key!')
            pyautogui.hotkey('f5') 

    except:
        break
```

Comment: maybe `keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl') and keyboard.is_pressed('alt')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would display error -  i.e.

```
except Exception as ex:
    print('Exception:', ex)
```

then you would see (at least on Linux)

```
Exception: Impossible to check if multi-step hotkeys are pressed (`a+b` is ok, `a, b` isn't).
```

And this would show you that you need `ctrl+alt` instead of `ctrl,alt`

```
import keyboard

while True:
    try:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl+alt'):
            print('You Pressed ctrl+alt')
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Exception:', ex)
        break
```

---

**EDIT:**

Also works for me

```
if keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl') and keyboard.is_pressed('alt'):
```

and `add_hotkey()`

```
import keyboard

def update():
    print('You Pressed ctrl+alt')

keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+alt', update)

keyboard.wait('esc')  # press `Esc` to end program
```